# JavaScript - How to use onclick function also with keyboard

Tags: javascript, onclick, keyboard-events

I have this code in HTML & JavaScript:

```
<button id="Z">Z</button>

var btnZ = document.getElementById("Z");
btnZ.onclick = function() {
    // Some code
}
```

I want to execute `btnZ.onclick` function when the user presses "Z" on keyboard. How can I do this without duplicating the code inside `btnZ.onclick` function?

Comment: Just make a named function?

Comment: OnClick is a full mouse click (down + release). For keyboard use onKeyUp. I'm on mobile and typing the full function takes an eternity so look up the latest method gor keyup or keypress...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
function clicked () {
    alert('clicked!');
    //some code
}
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 90) {
        clicked();
    }
};
btnZ.onclick = clicked;
```

Comment: I didn't know about onkeydown function, but it's really helpfull. Thanks @user3132718

Answer (score 6):

You should have a common function which executes the code, but then have two event functions.

```
function do() {
     //some code
}
btnZ.onclick = function(e) {
    do();
};
btnZ.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode === 90) do();
}
```

This will only work if the user is focused on the element.

Comment: You can use 'onkeyup' if you prefer the code executes once.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use HTML5, you can use the [`accesskey` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) (but it will respond to ALT + Z, and not Z only).

If you can't use HTML5, you must use the `keydown` event.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I know w3shools is not always good. But what site should i use when i want to link some html documentation ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes - Mozilla's documentation for HTML/CSS/Javascript is far better in both quality and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the function separately and just refer to it wherever you need it. For example,

```
 var yourOnClickFunction =  function() {
                               // Some code
 btnZ.onclick = yourOnClickFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to trigger event of other element as shown in [below example](http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/okDBI)

```
<button >Hello</button>
clickButton = function(){
  alert("Hello clicked")
}
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = clickButton

keydown = function(e){
 if(e.keyCode==90)
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click()
}
document.onkeydown = keydown
```

if using JQuery you can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function. Following is sample code and also find working example in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/ByswA)

```
<button >Hello</button>

$("button").click(function(){
  alert("Hello clicked")
})

$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.charCode == 90)
    $("button").trigger("click")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button id="z">Z</button>
```

**JS**

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) { 
  e = e || window.event; 
  var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode, 
      character = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 

  if (character == 'z')
  alert(character);
};

document.getElementById('z').onclick = function (e){
    alert(document.getElementById('z').id)
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/k8bmY/)